# how to highlight index nav link when on root page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

So there's one web design project I'm working on, and I've run into a bit of a problem I've been trying to resolve. I've been working on highlighting different nav links based on url of current page. It works on every page I've been working on except for the index page when you land to that page through root link. Even knowing the issue may seems minor if everything else works, but it does bother me a little, hey, I like a good challenge though. I've been trying to set it up in jquery so the index link get highlighted whenever someone is at the root links but I've had no success. I'm also out of ideas on what to try. If anyone can give me help that would be great.

Here's all the relevant pieces of code

**HTML**:

```
<nav class="main">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="pink">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" class="orange">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="purple">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

**CSS**:

```
    nav.main ul li a
    {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.57em;
    padding: 0.1em 1.5em;
    padding-top: 0.3em;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent
    }

    nav.main ul li a.pink:hover
    {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #d9618f;
    transition: 295ms ease;
    }

    nav.main ul li a.apink
    {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #d9618f;
    }

    nav.main ul li a.orange:hover
    {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #5ee9ef;;
    transition: 295ms ease;
    }

    nav.main ul li a.aorange
    {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #5ee9ef;
    }

    nav.main ul li a.purple:hover
    {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #9648a5;
    transition: 295ms ease;
    }

    nav.main ul li a.apurple
    {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #9648a5;
    }
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(function () {

    $('nav.main ul li a[href="index.html' + location.pathname.split("index.html")[1] + '"]').addClass('apink');

    $('nav.main ul li a[href="about.html' + location.pathname.split("about.html")[3] + '"]').addClass('aorange');

    $('nav.main ul li a[href="contact.html' + location.pathname.split("contact.html")[4] + '"]').addClass('apurple');

    $('nav.main ul li a[href="index.html' + location.pathname.split("schedule.html")[5] + '"]').addClass('apink');

    $('nav.main ul li a[href="contact.html' + location.pathname.split("thanks.html")[6] + '"]').addClass('apurple');


});
```

Comment: When you in root page what exactly your path is coming at url bar?

Comment: http://hoopactivation.x10.mx/ shows when I look at the url bar.

Comment: The site you provided is working fine for `index.html` by adding `apink` class to top anchor. Have you clear the cache after changes?

Comment: That's because there's some older code on the site I'm using as a temporary fix, but it isn't that great of code though.

Comment: Nor is it that efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your root page, add class to **index.html** anchor element

```
$("nav.main ul li a:first-child").addClass('apink');
```

Comment: except the root page is the index page. I'm talking about adding the class to the index anchor when the url is

http://example.com/

    NOT

          http://example.com/index.html

Comment: There wont be any url right except your domain name when you are in root page. So, inside root page itself add the class to the anchor element. Got it..!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this code by Jonathan Snook

```
/*
CLCP v2.1 Clear Links to Current Page
Jonathan Snook
This code is offered unto the public domain
http://www.snook.ca/jonathan/
*/

window.onload = clearCurrentLink;

function clearCurrentLink(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) if(a[i].href="=" window.location.href.split("#")[0])="" removenode(a[i]);="" }="" function="" removenode(n){="" if(n.haschildnodes())="" gets="" the="" text="" from="" link="" and="" moves="" it="" to="" previous="" node.="" for(var="" i="0;i<n.childNodes.length;i++)" {="" var="" strong="document.createElement('strong');" label="n.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true);" strong.appendchild(label);="" n.parentnode.appendchild(strong);="" n.parentnode.removechild(n);="" <="" pre="">
</a.length;i++)>
```

Comment: Do I use it as is, or do I have to do any tweaking?